# adpboilerplate ASP.NET Core MVC Login Loop in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I followed the instructions to install and run the ASP.NET Core MVC ADP template:
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Core

When I login in Chrome, it keeps looping back to the login page.  The login is successful, but I'm not logged in and can't access the home page.  I've checked the Chrome console and there are no errors or .

It works fine in FireFox.

My Chrome version (Windows 10) is:
81.0.4044.129 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been seeing the same issue as well, in the Chromium version of Edge, I've just managed to rectify, a couple of the things that have helped

- Change the `Authentication.JwtBearer.IsEnabled` value to false, and then toggle it back to true
- Clear all local storage under `dev tools -> application -> clear storage`